# Assigning a numeric value to a string through calling a function in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a blackjack simulator in Python 3 and I am trying to define a function that will assign a numeric value to the card it deals. I believe I am making a mistake when calling my function.

```
{
import random
import CardVal

cards = [
'AS', '2S', '3S', '4S', '5S', '6S', '7S', '8S', '9S', 'TS', 'JS', 'QS', 'KS',
'AC', '2C', '3C', '4C', '5C', '6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC', 'JC', 'QC', 'KC',
'AD', '2D', '3D', '4D', '5D', '6D', '7D', '8D', '9D', 'TD', 'JD', 'QD', 'KD',
'AH', '2H', '3H', '4H', '5H', '6H', '7H', '8H', '9H', 'TH', 'JH', 'QH', 'KH'
]
decks = 6 * cards


player = []
dealer = []

for i in range(2):
    player.append(decks.pop(random.randrange(len(decks) - 1)))
    dealer.append(decks.pop(random.randrange(len(decks) - 1)))


print('Players cards:', player)
print('Dealers card:', dealer[1])


total = 0
for i in range(len(player)):
    CardVal.card_value(player[i])

    total += player[i]
}
```

And here is the function I am calling

```
{
def card_value(card):
    if '2' in card:
        card = 2
    elif '3' in card:
        card = 3
    elif '4' in card:
        card = 4
    elif '5' in card:
        card = 5
    elif '6' in card:
        card = 6
    elif '7' in card:
        card = 7
    elif '8' in card:
        card = 8
    elif '9' in card:
        card = 9
    elif 'T' in card or 'J' in card or 'Q' in card or 'K' in card:
        card = 10
    elif 'A' in card:
        card = 11
}
```

Comment: Use a dictionary instead..

Comment: What output are you getting?  What do you expect to get?

Comment: What's with the braces?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a dictionary:

```
def card_value(card):
    values = {'T': 10, 'J': 10, 'Q': 10, 'K': 10, 'A': 11}
    if card[0].isdigit():
        return int(card[0])
    else:
        return values[card[0]]
```

Comment: the card strings have the Suit as well as the value - 'AS' and '9H'

Comment: @robert_x44 ^ right so i need the code to know that all T's are 10 regardless of suit. Idk how to do that with a dictionary